# Introducing oneself in past tense on the phone

Tags: swedish

In Swedish it seems very common to initially refer to oneself in the past tense when talking on the phone, "hej, det här var Nisse Hult från nonsensbyrån...", "hi, this was Nisse Hult from the nonsense bureau..."

Why is this? Is it a form of weasling, do we Swedes feel "this is" is too harsh/direct a way to refer to oneself?

Comment: This question does not seek usage guidance but linguistic explanation; no need to close it. -- Welcome to the site, Erik!

Comment: I'd like to remark that a similar thing happens in Norwegian too: Norwegians are often heard saying things like "dette var godt" (this was good) while enjoy a meal.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open because it's *not a Language-specific grammar and usage question*

Comment: The only vaguely comparable thing I can think of in English is at the end of an on-location news report: _This was John Doe in New York_. It would be odd in a phone conversation.

Comment: Yes or *I've been John Doe, thanks very much ladies and gentlemen* at the end of a standup routine.

Comment: @OmarL That’s common in Swedish too (though not in Danish in the food context). Backshifting as a way of hedging/weaselling (or whatever it is exactly) is quite common in Scandinavian in a variety of situations. I’d say overall Swedish does it more than Norwegian, which does it more than Danish. In Danish it’s especially found in exclamatory phrases meaning ‘well that’s good/bad’ (“det var (ikke så) godt”, “det var dog irriterende”, etc.), where it’s also very common in both Norwegian and Swedish.

Comment: (Also used in Danish on phone: "Ja goddag, det var Jens Hansen..")

Comment: I don't find "dette var godt" or "det var dog irriterende" odd, the former is as if to say "this [food] turned out to be good (after all)", the latter is about something that's happened, whence naturally "was".
And no I'm not seeking "usage guidance", I'm a Swede and know all the ways to talk on the phone in Swedish, thx...

Comment: @Erik “Det var dog irriterende” and similar are also used in situations where the irritant is an ongoing thing. For example, I believe I said those exact words mere minutes ago in the context of “Det var dog irriterende så elendigt jeg server i dag!” while playing badminton and serving like a pack of mashed potatoes. My inability to serve was not a past-tense thing, but something that had lasted all night and continued long after I moaned about it.

Comment: In Russian they *Пошли* while i.e. before leaving, although it means *We left*.  And in German *Gesagt getan* after hearing an order but before fulfilling.  But in those cases it's more like inflation, it's logical why it shifted.

Answer (score 2):

I have no references for this, I'm merely a native Swedish speaker with linguistics as a keen armature interest, but I have a hypothesis:

**Whatever is going on, past tense seems to be used in a similar way in other languages, such as English or Spanish. I think the past tense could be considered a "polite verb form", though it may (have evolved to?) be used in other-than-polite ways as well.**

In English, I would interpret the following as a polite present tense, though of course they could be interpreted literally as well.

- Could you show me the way?
- I was wondering if you could pass some potatoes.
- I wanted to ask you for help.

*Could* and *would* are probably the most common words used in this context. (If someone objects that they are really conditional, not past tense, my point still holds: People use verb forms outside their literal meaning for politeness)

I know similar constructs in Spanish, and I think I remember there's something similar in German, though I'm less certain.

In Swedish, the following makes sense in a present-tense context:

- Jag hade en fråga. (I had a question)
- Ville du ha något? (Did you want something?)
- (archaic) Ville Fröken ha något? (Did the Miss (you) want something?)
- Namnet var Karl. (My name is Karl, lit. The name was Karl)

I include the archaic form addressing someone with *Fröken* for the sake of possible Swedish readers, as I find that trying to talk like an old movie make these past-tense constructions show up all the time.

I'm not sure they are necessarily more polite than they would be in present tense, but polite language and politeness don't always go hand in hand. (Compare the, admittedly extreme, English example "Would someone please put the bastard out of his fucking misery?". Despite all the polite forms and the euphemism, it's quite rude.)

TL;DR
Whatever is going on, it's not limited to answering the phone. It's not unique to Swedish but happens in English and other languages as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak a word of Swedish or Norwegian, but since there are no other answers, allow me to propose a hypothesis:

`This was Nisse Hult` started out as an answer to what used to be an implied question `Who rang the phone?`